# Remove an item from grid which should have always exactly 6 columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an html structure like shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VrkU5/7/. I hope it is clear enough.

**div.item** with .item only class is item which contains something, let say an image. **div.item.empty** is empty, with a placeholder.

Row example:

```
<div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            <div class="item">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <div class="item">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <div class="item">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <div class="item">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <div class="item empty">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <div class="item empty">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem:

I want to remove an item form this list and replace it with an empty one. Everything is working fine, I can remove it and append an empty one to div.row-fluid. But my problem is that I could have multiple rows....

If one item is removed from a row, script should get one item from next, closest row, append it to first row (from which item was removed), and append empty.

I need to have always 6 item in each row.

I am looking forward for the simplest way of doing this. I am using jQuery. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Welcome to stack. Your fiddle and question are not clear enough. You speak about colums in grid rows. I did not see any columns in the fiddle mark up. Also, there are no items present in the row. Phrase your question properly and apply proper mark up to the fiddle to make it right. Also, there has been no effort from your end to write js code to support your requirements . Try to do that first and then if there appears to be some problem, post it here. Stack guys will look it up to help you. Cheers !

Comment: can you explain again what you want... you need to remove which item from the row?

Comment: Ok, I have updated fiddle with javascript that I already have. Basically, this rows are displayed in slider. I wanna create something like a basket. You can add item, remove it, but items have to be 6 per row always. If there are for example 3 items in row, i wanna add 3 more placeholder with a plus icon. Here is an image of the prototype: http://oi44.tinypic.com/2u6cro1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is bootstrap actually, it was causing a ton of problems. I removed it from JS fiddle and used this CSS as well as added a clearer div at the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/VrkU5/23/

```
.row-fluid > div.span2{float:left;margin-left:0px;width:16%;}
.clearer {clear:both;}
.item {
    width: 86%;
    padding: 5%;
    color: #fff;
    background: #ff0000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 1.4em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.item.empty {
    background: #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it is working fine, but unfortunately this html structure will be part of a slider (RoyalSlider exactly) and every <div></div> (without a class) is one slide. I want to remove an item from one slide, but if there are items in other slider it should go to previous one.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to write custom code for each then. You cant really take an element from another div without having it coded for each.

Comment: Yeah, i know. But my questions was about the simplest way to do it. Just algorithm or sth. Code I can write my self... After 1 day of working on it, I think that the best option will be to remove all of them, remove rows and create all dom from scratches that moving items form div to div... What u think?

Comment: I use that technique a lot since I use Smarty and fetch code snippets through AJAX. However, if your data doesn't need to be updated from the database, I think it is best to store it locally in a javascript variable to minimize bandwidth and server connections. 

Either way, your solution is probably the simplest way to get it done with multiple divs for your needs. A nice fadeOut - update the html - fadeIn effect could make it look as if there isn't any rebuilding going on too.